# jquery selector using the 'not:' twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<input type="text" class="incorrect">
<input type="text" class="correct">
<input type="text" class="defalut">
<input type="text" class="correct">
<input type="text" class="incorrect">
<input type="text" class="">
```

I'm using jquery .
I mean , now I'm focused on the first input (which has class of incorrect) . I want to get the next input that has neither class=default nor class=correct . How to realise it ?
I try

```
input:not(.correct):not(.defalut)
```

or

```
input:not(.correct .defalut)
```

But it seems not working !
Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate classnames using comma. If you want the focus to be on elements other than the  first one, and does not have class 'correct' or 'defalut', then use the following. Here I've used [**`filter()`**](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) function and [**`slice()`**](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) function to not select first element.

Here

```js
var count = $('input:not(.correct, .defalut)').length;
alert( "Number of inputs not have classnames 'correct' or 'defalut' : " + count );
$('input').slice(1).filter(':not(.correct, .defalut)').first().focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="incorrect">
<input type="text" class="correct">
<input type="text" class="defalut">
<input type="text" class="correct">
<input type="text" class="incorrect">
<input type="text" class="">
```

Answer (score 1):

> now I'm focused on the first input (which has class of incorrect)

Try using `:first` to select first `.incorrect` `input` element , next siblings selector , `:not()` with selectors `.correct, .default` , `:first` again to select first element that does not have `class` `.correct` or `.default`

Note `"default"` is spelled `"defalut"` at third `input` element , adjusted at `html` at stacksnippets to `"default"`

```js
$(".incorrect:first ~ input:not(.correct, .default):first")
.css("border", "2px solid sienna")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="incorrect">
<input type="text" class="correct">
<input type="text" class="default">
<input type="text" class="correct">
<input type="text" class="incorrect">
<input type="text" class="">
```